# Integrate custom Oauth provider with firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, twitch-api

I setup a Twitch OAuth integration using the [Instagram example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/instagram-auth), now I can login into my app by opening the `popup.html` page that the example gave me.

Here's my adapted code:

```js
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const { AuthorizationCode } = require('simple-oauth2');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

// Firebase Setup
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
// @ts-ignore
const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseio.com`,
});

const OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI = `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com/popup.html`;;
const OAUTH_SCOPES = 'user:read:email';

/**
 * Creates a configured simple-oauth2 client for Twitch.
 */
function twitchOAuth2Client() {
  // Twitch OAuth 2 setup
  // TODO: Configure the `twitch.client_id` and `twitch.client_secret` Google Cloud environment variables.
  const credentials = {
    client: {
      id: functions.config().twitch.client_id,
      secret: functions.config().twitch.client_secret,
    },
    auth: {
      tokenHost: 'https://id.twitch.tv',
      tokenPath: '/oauth2/token',
      authorizePath: '/oauth2/authorize',
    },
    options: {
      bodyFormat: 'json',
      authorizationMethod: 'body',
    },
  };
  return new AuthorizationCode(credentials);
}

/**
 * Redirects the User to the Twitch authentication consent screen. Also the 'state' cookie is set for later state
 * verification.
 */
exports.redirect = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const authorizationCode = twitchOAuth2Client();

  cookieParser()(req, res, () => {
    const state = req.cookies.__session || crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
    console.log('Setting verification state:', state);
    res.cookie('__session', state.toString(), { maxAge: 3600000, httpOnly: true });
    const redirectUri = authorizationCode.authorizeURL({
      redirect_uri: OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
      scope: OAUTH_SCOPES,
      state: state,
    });
    console.log('Redirecting to:', redirectUri);
    res.redirect(redirectUri);
  });
});

/**
 * Exchanges a given Twitch auth code passed in the 'code' URL query parameter for a Firebase auth token.
 * The request also needs to specify a 'state' query parameter which will be checked against the 'state' cookie.
 * The Firebase custom auth token, display name, photo URL and Twitch acces token are sent back in a JSONP callback
 * function with function name defined by the 'callback' query parameter.
 */
exports.token = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const authorizationCode = twitchOAuth2Client();

  try {
    cookieParser()(req, res, async () => {
      try {
        console.log('Received verification state:', req.cookies.__session);
        console.log('Received state:', req.query.state);
        if (!req.cookies.__session) {
          throw new Error(
            'State cookie not set or expired. Maybe you took too long to authorize. Please try again.'
          );
        } else if (req.cookies.__session !== req.query.state) {
          throw new Error('State validation failed');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return res.jsonp({ error: error.toString() });
      }

      let accessToken;
      try {
        console.log('Received auth code:', req.query.code);
        const options = {
          client_id: functions.config().twitch.client_id,
          client_secret: functions.config().twitch.client_secret,
          code: req.query.code,
          grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          redirect_uri: OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
        };
        console.log('Asking token with options', JSON.stringify(options));
        accessToken = await authorizationCode.getToken(options);
        console.log('Auth code exchange result received');

        const twitchUser = await getTwitchUser(accessToken.toJSON().access_token);

        // Create a Firebase account and get the Custom Auth Token.
        const firebaseToken = await createFirebaseAccount(twitchUser);

        // Serve an HTML page that signs the user in and updates the user profile.
        return res.jsonp({ token: firebaseToken });
      } catch (error) {
        return res.jsonp({ error: error.toString() });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.jsonp({ error: error.toString() });
  }
});

/**
 * Creates a Firebase account with the given user profile and returns a custom auth token allowing
 * signing-in this account.
 *
 * @returns {Promise<string>} The Firebase custom auth token in a promise.
 */
async function createFirebaseAccount(twitchUser) {
  // The UID we'll assign to the user.
  const uid = `twitch:${twitchUser.id}`;

  // Save the access token to the Firebase Database.
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const databaseTask = db.collection('users').doc(uid).set(twitchUser);

  // Create or update the user account.
  const userCreationTask = admin
    .auth()
    .updateUser(uid, {
      displayName: twitchUser['display_name'],
      photoURL: twitchUser['profile_image_url'],
      email: twitchUser['email'],
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // If user does not exists we create it.
      if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
        return admin.auth().createUser({
          uid: uid,
          displayName: twitchUser['display_name'],
          photoURL: twitchUser['profile_image_url'],
          email: twitchUser['email'],
        });
      }
      throw error;
    });

  // Wait for all async task to complete then generate and return a custom auth token.
  await Promise.all([userCreationTask, databaseTask]);
  // Create a Firebase custom auth token.
  const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
  console.log('Created Custom token for UID "', uid, '" Token:', token);
  return token;
}

async function getTwitchUser(accessToken) {
  console.log('Fetching Twitch user with access_token', accessToken);
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Client-Id': functions.config().twitch.client_id,
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
      },
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return { ...data.data[0], access_token: accessToken };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

I'd like, though, to login into Twitch using the `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect()` method that I already use for Facebook and Google, unfortunately I can't find any documentation about this, and the [Facebook provider source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/a9ba7ba7c2b9da8bd16f14c0062593bd8d941124/packages-exp/auth-exp/src/core/providers/facebook.ts) refers to some [`externs.*`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/a9ba7ba7c2b9da8bd16f14c0062593bd8d941124/packages-exp/auth-exp/src/core/providers/facebook.ts#L66-L73) resources so I'm not sure how to adapt it for my own needs.

Right now I have two endpoints/cloud functions: `_twitchRedirect` and `_twitchToken`, what should I do to integrate them with `signInWithRedirect`?

Comment: From the Facebook source you linked it has: `import * as externs from '@firebase/auth-types-exp';` You can find that file at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/a9ba7ba7c2b9da8bd16f14c0062593bd8d941124/packages-exp/auth-types-exp with the definitions in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/a9ba7ba7c2b9da8bd16f14c0062593bd8d941124/packages-exp/auth-types-exp/index.d.ts

Comment: It looks like this might relate to the OpenID Connect flow when using Google Cloud Identity Platform with Firebase: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc

Answer (score 7):

I was similarly curious, so spent a little time playing around with things today.

In short, when using Firebase Auth, I believe the `providerId` will need to be one of the existing supported providers.

If you upgrade to using the Google Cloud Identity Platform though, I believe you will be able to configure custom providers, and then use this function to authenticate:

- https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform

We can see that `firebase.auth.OAuthProvider` and `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup` (or `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect`) are used with a number of the providers here, eg.

- https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/apple
- https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/microsoft

In addition to these provider choices that we get with the standard Firebase Auth, Google Cloud Identity Platform allows us to also add SAML and OpenID Connect (OIDC) integrations:

- https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml
- https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc

When adding a new identity provider using either of these, we are able to specify the 'Provider ID' to use (prefixed with either `saml.` or `oidc.`). This custom provider ID is then used with `firebase.auth.OAuthProvider` and `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup` (or `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect`) as described above.

For example, if I created a new identity provider with an ID of `oidc.foo`, my integration code would end up looking like:

```js
const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('oidc.foo');

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((result) => {
    // result.credential is a firebase.auth.OAuthCredential object.
    // result.credential.providerId is equal to 'oidc.foo'.
    // result.credential.idToken is the OIDC provider's ID token.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle error.
  });
```

Based on my understanding of this, I believe we will only currently be able to add custom providers this way if they conform to the OpenID Connect (OIDC) standard (including the OIDC Discovery part, which uses a `/.well-known/openid-configuration` URL):

> Note: If your OIDC provider doesn't comply with the [OIDC specification for discovery](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfig), it won't work with Identity Platform.

So to my knowledge, the best way to implement 'normal' OAuth2 providers currently is the custom backend function flow you used above (based on the Firebase Auth examples).

---

As part of figuring this out, I decided to see what would happen if I used a provider ID that didn't match anything configured in my account (this is a fairly verbose step by step, and the main answer is already included above, but this may help provide some more context/help someone out, so including it here)

```js
var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider("foo.example.com");
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithRedirect(provider)
      .then((result) => console.log("OAuthProvider:", result))
      .catch((error) => console.log("OAuthProvider::error:", error));

firebase
  .auth()
  .getRedirectResult()
  .then((result) => console.log("RedirectResult:", result))
  .catch((error) => console.log("RedirectResult::error:", error));
```

At first I go this `auth/auth-domain-config-required` error:

```
OAuthProvider::error: {
    "code": "auth/auth-domain-config-required",
    "message": "Be sure to include authDomain when calling firebase.initializeApp(), by following the instructions in the Firebase console."
}
```

I figured maybe this should be set to the OAuth provider I was wanting to login to, so I set `authDomain` in my firebase config to `foo.myauthprovider.com`, but when I called `signInWithRedirect`, it tried to load the following URL (where the `apiKey` is the API key of my firebase project), which failed to load:

```
https://foo.myauthprovider.com/__/auth/handler?apiKey=REDACTED&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&authType=signInViaRedirect&providerId=foo.example.com&redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&v=7.14.5
```

This `/__/auth/handler` URL is part of Firebase Auth's reserved URLs, which you can read more about at:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#auth_helpers

And is explained a little better in this StackOverflow answer, but is basically what Firebase Auth uses to handle OAuth callbacks to avoid needing to expose sensitive credentials on the frontend, and so users don't need to implement their own handlers all the time):

- [Why does Firebase auth uses a "middleware" redirect before returning to my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53990604/why-does-firebase-auth-uses-a-middleware-redirect-before-returning-to-my-app/54002778#54002778)

Changing `authDomain` to the actual custom domain of my firebase project fixed that issue, and then resulted in the following `auth/operation-not-allowed` error when I tried to redirect:

```
RedirectResult::error: u {code: "auth/operation-not-allowed", message: "The identity provider configuration is not found.", a: null}
```